# Where should event handlers be placed in a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, events, service

I'm trying to convert a console application project into a windows service.

My dummy console app project was listening to access events from a third-party API ([NET2 sdk](http://www.paxton.co.uk/Forum/posts/m33-Net2-SDK-Examples#post33)) and was printing their info to console. I'd like to transform it to run in the background as a windows service.

However I'm having hard time keeping the event handler "alive" so it keeps capturing access events while the service is running.

Currently I have placed it inside the onStart() function like this:

```
Net2 net2;

public Net2MonitoringService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
    if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("Net2 Monitoring Service"))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
            "Net2 Monitoring Service", "Net2 Monitoring Log");
    }
    eventLog1.Source = "Net2 Monitoring Service";
    eventLog1.Log = "Net2 Monitoring Log";
}

  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Net2 Monitoring Service has started.");
        net2 = new Net2();
        net2.Login();

        //Monitor main door events
        net2.client.MonitorAcu(1172079);
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Monitoring door #1172079. Listening for events...", EventLogEntryType.Information);

        //Create an event handler to handle the access event
        net2.client.Net2AccessEvent += new OemClient.Net2AcuEventHandler(Net2AccessEvent);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        net2.Logout();
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Net2 Monitoring Service has stopped.");
    }

    private void Net2AccessEvent(object sender, IEventView e)
    {
        //Print access event details to log
        string message = "Access event triggered:\n" +
            "UserId: " + e.UserId.ToString() + "\n" +
            "EventId: " + e.UserId.ToString() + "\n" +
            "Address: " + e.UserId.ToString() + "\n" +
            "SubAddress: " + e.UserId.ToString() + "\n" +
            "EventDateTime: " + e.UserId.ToString() + "\n";
        eventLog1.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit);
    }
```

The above code results in never triggering the Net2AccessEvent method even there are events to be captured.

---

**PS:** The same code worked fine while being executed inside the Main() of the console application when triggered from Visual Studio debugger that keeps the main thread alive.

Comment: Windows service apps run in session 0 and is fully isolated from user sessions. So not every libraries can work in that case and you need to consult the library vendor.

Comment: @LexLi so the above code structure looks fine? The Net2 SDK provides events from a remote access server so I'm not really sure that its the service's runtime environment that causes the problem..

Comment: I can also confirm that the SKD supports running inside Windows Services (http://www.paxton.co.uk/Forum/posts/t794-Net2-SDK-usage-in-Windows-Service).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question some days later, the problem seems to be solved after using a singleton to avoid losing scope on the monitoring and run it on the OnStart() method.

Comment: sharing some code snippet would be great help - Thanks

Comment: @lephleg I am having the same issue, I can not keep the event handler alive for the Net2AcuEventHandler, the event is not triggered once. How did you solved this?

Comment: Hey folks, sorry for the late reply. It's been a while and I'm not sure I still have tha code. I'll take a look into my drives and I'll let you know...